# Transfer only rows that have different values as existing table data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres and have 2 tables Transaction and Backup.
I would like to transfer rows of data from Transaction to Backup.

There will be new rows of data in Transaction table.

How do I transfer only rows of data that have different values as the existing data in Transaction table as I do not want to have duplicate rows of data?

As long as data in 1 of the column is different, I will transfer the row from Transaction to Backup.

e.g
Day 1: Transaction (20 rows) , Backup (20 rows)    [All transaction file being backup to Backup at night]

Day 2: Transaction (40 rows), Backup(20 rows) [The additional 20 rows in Transaction may contain duplicate rows as the previous 20 rows in Transaction. I only want to transfer non-duplicate rows to Backup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading between the lines I think this is a harder question than you know.

The real issue here is that you don't really know what has changed.  If information is append-only and we can assume they are all visible when the last backup was made then we just select rows inserted after a point in time.  If these are not good assumptions, then you are going to have a long-term issue.  a_horse_with_no_name has an ok solution above assuming your data is append-only (all inserts, no updates), but it is not going to perform very well as these tables bet bigger.

A few options you might consider instead:

1. A table audit trigger would allow you to specify columns, values, etc as well as when they are changed and it could do this real-time.  That would be my first solution.
2. Even if it is insert only you may want to store information in the backup table regarding max ids or the like and go back only one backup in checking.  Then you could use a_horse_with_no_name's solution as a template.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to copy data *from* the transactions table *to* the backup table.

Something like this should do it. As you haven't shown us the actual table definitions I had to use dummy names for the columns. `pk_col` is the primary key column of the table.

```
insert into backup (pk_col, col1, col2, col3, col4)
select t.*
from transactions t
  full outer join backup b on t.pk_col = b.pk_col
where t is distinct from b;
```

This assumes that the target table does not have a unique key. If it does you need to use an `ON CONFLICT` clause

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to transfer rows from table `Source` to table `Result`. From your question, I understand that they have the same columns.

As you mentioned, you need values from `Source` different from the ones, that are already in `Result`.

```
SELECT * FROM [Source]
WHERE column NOT IN (SELECT column FROM Result)
```

It will return ,,new" records. Now you need insert it:

```
INSERT INTO Result 
SELECT * FROM [Source]
WHERE column NOT IN (SELECT column FROM Result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
insert into Backup (fields1, fields2, ......)
     select fields1, fields2 from Transaction t where your condition by date here and  not exists (select * from Backup b where t.fields1 = b.fields1
        t.fields2 = b.fields2
        .....................
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This will insert if any changes happens in transaction table. if you change an existing row from transaction table -NULL also included- will be inserted into backup table. but you shouldnt have primary key in your backup table because you wont be able to insert  that row:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tb_backup_pkey"

will comes out.

this should work for entire row:

```
insert into backup (col1, col2, col3, col4)
select t.* from transactions t
EXCEPT
select * from backup b
```